# How to Create A "Do you want to Continue?" Alert Box

Tags: java, android

In my application I have a button that when pressed I want it to display an Alert Dialog Box that asks if you want to continue. It will have two buttons: a "Continue" and "Do Not Continue". I am putting the method that opens up the dialog box within the method that opens the new Activity like so:

```
case R.id.bRegister:
          try{
              //the method for opening the alert box goes somewhere here but i don't know where yet.
              Class ourClass = Class.forName("org.health.blablablabla.app.RegisterData");
              Intent ourIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ourClass);
              finish();

              startActivity(ourIntent);
              overridePendingTransition(R.animator.fadein,R.animator.fadeout);

          } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```

This is currently what I have for the Alert Dialog Box method:

```
 private void showWarning(){
    AlertDialog.Builder warning = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    warning.setTitle("Existing Data");
    warning.setMessage("There is already existing data. If you continue all previous data will be deleted. Are you sure you want to continue?");
    warning.setPositiveButton("Continue",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
        {
            arg0.dismiss();
        }
    });
    warning.setNegativeButton("Do Not Continue",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
}
```

My question is where to put the method in the first block of code, and how do I make it so that when the "Do Not Continue" button is pressed, the New Activity "RegisterData" doesn't open up.

Comment: google dialogfragment and use it.. okay, because alertdialog.builder will give you exceptions because its deprecated..okay.. so google and put the alertdialog.builder code in your oncreatedialog in the dialog fragment..this doesn't answer your question, i am just offering a helping hand to you, now this answers your question, when you want to leave the activity then you show the dialog, when the user clicks continue then you start the activity using the startactivity()

Answer (score 1):

you can make an YesNoSampleActivity and use AlertDialog.Builder like this:

```
public class YesNoSampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Put up the Yes/No message box
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder
    .setTitle("Erase hard drive")
    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                    
            //Yes button clicked, do something
            Toast.makeText(YesNoSampleActivity.this, "Yes button pressed", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", null)                      //Do nothing on no
    .show();


    // Continue code after the Yes/No dialog
    // ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I figured out a solution that worked for me.

Comment: your welcome,so put your answer by yourself here and accept that by yours! or accept my answer because your question should have an true accepted answer.tnx